# What's discounted rate used in the cap option

Tags: options, bond

Here is a example of `Cap option` in John Holl's book `Options, Futures and Other Derivatives  9th` `page 681.`

One thing I am confused that there are two discounted rate, one is `LIBOR/swap zero curve is flat at 7%` and the other is `The continuously compounded zero rate for all maturities is 6.9395%.`

Here we use forward price $F_k,$ it seems we should use the `LIBOR` as the a discounted rate.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7% annual LIBOR with quarterly payment = 4 * 1.75% coupons

1.0175 ^ 4 = 1.071859

ln(1.071859) = 6.9395%, the continuously compounded rate.

This is the second question you ask about converting yields with different quoting conventions, I suggest you read some literature about this before attempting more complex equations. By the way it's John Hull, John Holl is writing beer guides.